# How to Disable Direct Write in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, fonts, directx, rendering, cleartype

I find ClearType, Direct Write, etc. font rendering systems not very aesthetically pleasing. So I download a free software called MacType on my Windows 10. The problem is that it does not render everything on Windows 10. I was able to make it run on Chrome by disabling direct write from Chrome://flags. I have read multiple articles in which they explained that Mac type only will work on places where GDI++ is being used. Places where Direct Write is present, Mac Type will not work. Also from Office 2013, they office applications started using direct write to render the fonts. So is there are way I can disable direct write individually from office. Also is there a way I can disable direct write from the entire windows 10 OS. I have tried going into the directx diagnostic tool but there is not editing options there. Please Help!

Regards,
Akhil

Comment: Because using or not using DirectWrite is a decision that a developer makes, you can't force programs (not)  to use it unless the program already supports both.

Comment: So there is absolutely noway I can enable Mac Type throughout my Windows 10. I mean I was wondering if I could change some files from windows 10 or put some command through the cmd.exe to change the settings.

Comment: It’s not entirely impossible. It’s as *easy* as creating a new DirectWrite implementation that uses MacType or whatever in the background.

Comment: Do you know how that's done. Like which file do I need to replace? How do I create a new DirectWrite implementation correctly? Maybe you can give me a link to a tutorials.

Comment: This is not about replacing files. It’s about writing C. You’d have to be a *very* seasoned Windows developer to pull that off. Of course there’s no such thing as tutorials on how to replace Windows core components, so you’d have to do most research on your own.

Comment: Where are some places I could research on my own? Do you know any trust-able sources? Thanks for all the help and clarification!

Comment: @Akhil - We cannot help you with finding those type of sources.

Comment: @DanielB and Ramhound - Thanks for all the help! I have a much better idea now of what needs to be done!

Comment: @Akhil What are those ideas?